# How can I remove all fragment when activity destroy

Tags: android, android-fragments

Do you know how can I clear all fragments in an activity, in layout and in backstack.

I know that we can clear backstack by using:

```
FragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

But what about in layout which I have dynamically added to layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I remove all fragment when activity destroy

All fragments are automatically destroyed when the activity holding them is destroyed.

Comment: Yes. Maybe I have something not clear. 
I have an activity and I add fragment A to activity's layout. When the activity recreate on orientation change. I wanna add new fragment to layout instead of the old one. I am newbie in fragment. Please help me:)
Sorry. My english is not really well.

Comment: @kdtphdav: Use a `FragmentTransaction` and `replace()`.

Comment: aha. it is simpler than I thought. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: hi. @CommonsWare : I am using Linear layout like a container. So. I can't using replace() method (It seem work wrong with linear layout). I am using remove() method and add() method instead of using replace method. But remove() method does not work for me in activity onCreate() method. Do you have any other solutions. Please help me. I may be fired if I can't solve this problem :(

Comment: hi. I resolved it. Instead of using LinearLayout like a container to contain 2 fragment. I am using two Framelayout in LinearLayout. Hix, It is simple and I don't know that. :(

Comment: Well, i have been scratching my head since 2 days to destroy all fragments when i exit the main activity. But still not found the solution. When i launch the app for second time, the fragments are displayed as blank.

Comment: The fragments are recreated in my case maintaining the backstack. But , I would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to bother. Once activity is destroyed all fragments will be destroyed too

Comment: So I do not need to delete fragment from FragmentManager in activity's onDestroy() method, if I added new fragment in activity's onCreate() method? How can I check that fragment is 100% have been destroyed after activity destroyed?